# Extracting values from a list and then arranging them in a data frame

Tags: r

I scraped an HTML table into R; however, all the data is contained in a jumbled list.

Here's what the output of one table looks like:

```
                                             Fighter                     KD                             Sig. str.
1 Colby Covington \n    \n    \n      Tyron Woodley 0\n    \n    \n      0 78 of 143\n    \n    \n      34 of 83
                 Sig. str. %                              Total str.                               Td
1 54%\n    \n    \n      40% 232 of 311\n    \n    \n      67 of 116 3 of 8\n    \n    \n      1 of 1
                         Td %               Sub. att                   Pass                   Rev.
1 37%\n    \n    \n      100% 0\n    \n    \n      0 2\n    \n    \n      0 0\n    \n    \n      0
```

Each data value is separated by`\n    \n    \n`       so I need to know how to use that to extract each value. On the website, each column; Fighter, KD, Sig. Str., etc, have two values, the odd-numbered one corresponding to the first fighter and the even to the second fighter. So, each column has two values associated with it, the first associated with the first fighter and the second with the second fighter.

As I am somewhat of a newbie to R and coding in general, I'm not quite sure how to actually extract each value I want and then store them in a tidy data.frame I can work on.

Here is my code:

```
library(tidyverse)
url<-"http://www.ufcstats.com/fight-details/ca531425f5c042db"
x<-read_html(url)
Totals<-x%>%
  html_nodes("table")%>%
  .[1]%>%
  html_table()
Totals
```

Any help or pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The table use `<p>` tags to identify rows, which is not standard and `rvest` couldn't regconize. You have to build the table yourself:

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
url <- "http://www.ufcstats.com/fight-details/ca531425f5c042db"
pg <- read_html(url)
table <- pg %>%
  html_nodes("table") %>%
  .[1]
table <- purrr::map_dfc(
  1:10,
  function(x) {
    data.frame(
      table %>% html_nodes("tr > td") %>% .[x] %>% html_nodes("p") %>% html_text()
    ) %>% 
      setNames(table %>% html_nodes("tr > th") %>% .[x] %>% html_text(trim = T))
  }
)
```